# sending additional data with a windows 8 push toast notification

Tags: windows-8, notifications, microsoft-metro

I'm building a windows 8 application wish toast notifications that are pushed. I know that when the toast is clicked, the application is started, possibly with the ability to see the payload of the toast that launched it.

However, is it possible for me to send additional data that can be interpreted by the client (like a unique id), that is not shown on the toast?

Comment: Related to the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13103149/1656796

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the **launch** attribute of the [Toast schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230846.aspx). What you put in there is up to you.  When the user clicks on the toast, the app will be activated with an [ActivationKind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.activation.activationkind.aspx) of **Launch**, and you can grab the string from the args passed into the [OnLaunched](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.application.onlaunched.aspx) handler (see [How to handle activation from a toast notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868212%28v=win.10%29.aspx))

Comment: great! please mark the question answered if indeed that's the case.