# Additional Parameters on Windows Notification Server

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, toast

I try sending push notification, I'm on server-side.
Is there a way in WNS, the push service for Windows 8, to send additional parameters, that will not be displayed.
On Windows Phone 7, I use the wp:Param as Follow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <wp:Notification xmlns:wp="WPNotification">
        <wp:Toast>
        .....
            <wp:Param></wp:Param>
        </wp:Toast>
    </wp:Notification>
```

Is there an equivalent for toast for exemple ?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/13103149/1656796

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For toast notifications, use the `launch` attribute in the [toast notification XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230846.aspx):

```
<toast launch="additionalContextParameters">
    ...
</toast>
```

The value specified in the `launch` attribute can be retrieved from the `Arguments` attribute passed into the `OnLaunched` handler (more details on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Hh868212%28v=win.10%29.aspx)).