# Windows interactive notifications

Tags: windows, win-universal-app, toast, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

So I want to know how a quickreply toast can be sent to the right person and when you click on it, it goes to the specific person.

Example 1:

Person A texts me, I pull down on the interactive notification and type my response and it gets processed by the background process. How does the applications know that my response goes to Person A. is there an attribute in the XML of the toast that can be a variable, like the phone number?

Example 2:

Person A posts a picture on my facebook, I click on the notification and it takes me to the page on facebook. Again is there an XML variable with a URL of it or something?

Comment: You put context in the `launch` or `arguments` attribute

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103149/determine-when-a-windows-8-app-is-launched-by-notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Notifications) Microsoft Windows UWP sample, where you can see what code they use to manage notifications.

I think that you need **Toast notifications**:

> Toast notifications are small pop ups that appear on the screen for few seconds. They convey messages and can be customized to even play different sounds. New to Windows 10 are actionable toasts where a user has a choice to interact with the notifications by use of a button, for example.

Comment: I did download that, but they didn't have any arguments, all they checked for was the button press.

Comment: @user298329 in example 2 you can use a button, with its content is an image. You can put in the button tag the url or the info that you need. You can also use arguments.